# Django Project Template Error: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I tend to use the same project template for a majority of my Django projects. Till now, I have been using copy-paste to use the template in different projects. 
(Sorry! I was unware of `--template` option that comes with `django-admin`.)

I got to know of `--template` option with `django-admin` a while back and I have a question regarding the same.

The aforementioned template that I use for my projects has some common Django apps, namely, `accounts` to handle user authentication, `pages` to handle request to pages like 'About', 'Contact', etc and some generic Django templates like `base.html`, templates for account activation email and password reset email.

Some of the generic Django templates (like the Sign In template) extend `base.html` in them. This is where the problem arises.

I get an error `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: base.html` when I try to use my project template with a new project.

Traceback:

```
$ django-admin startproject --template=/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/django-boilerplate/project_name --extension=py,html simpleqa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/bin/django-admin", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 20, in handle
    super().handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 154, in handle
    content = template.render(context)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 176, in render
    template = context.template.engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "/home/alfarhanzahedi/Projects/temp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 129, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name, tried=tried)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: base.html
```

The settings in `settings.py` is correctly configured as the project template seems to work  just fine via `python manage.py runserver`. All the Django templates load correctly.

I know that including Django templates within a project template offers very little help (or flexibility?), but I just wanted to know if this error has a solution!

I see that there is `--settings` option with `django-admin startproject`. I tried using it but to no avail!

Is there a solution to this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you use the options `--template=... --extension=py,html`, Django will render *all* you template files during the project creation. That means you would have to escape all template tags you want Django to ignore during the project creation.

It would probably be easier to put the project-specific bits of your template in your settings and pass them to your templates with a context processor.

If you are using the same apps in multiple projects you might also want to consider turning them into [reusable app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/reusable-apps/).

Comment: Escaping template tags seems like a cumbersome process. 
Now, my `base.html` (in my project template) includes `navbar.html` and `footer.html`. How to prevent any error while including the two templates in `base.html` while using the template in a new project?  
"It would probably be easier to put the project-specific bits of your template in your settings and pass them to your templates with a context processor." How will this work in this case?

Comment: Is there actually anything in your templates that you want to replace when starting a new project? Otherwise just use --extension=py and Django will copy your templates one-to-one.

Comment: I plan to remove html from `--extension` as a last resort. The only thing that I want to replace in the templates is {{project_name}} in the `<title></title>` tag. I will have to give up the rendering of the title of different pages if I choose to go with just `py` in `--extension`. 
I think I will skip `html` as there is no other way to achieve what I want. A possible solution would be write my own parser for starting a new Django project but that is way too complex and time-consuming for a task that has such a little and narrow (and maybe useless)  use-case!